# How to get the application directory of IOS simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was using

```
NSURL *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

to get the application directory in the IOS simulator. In my previous projects, I get path like:

> Users/username/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/30CF9489-8AE3-49D4-9E01-DC14EBA2E08D/Documents/

However, in one of my projects, it returns

> Users/username/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/30CF9489-8AE3-49D4-9E01-DC14EBA2E08D/Library/Documentation

Why they return two different paths while I am using the same method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the 2nd case you are using `NSDocumentationDirectory` instead of `NSDocumentDirectory`.

Comment: You are welcome. Please don't forget to close your question by accepting the answer.